# How to generalize methods with almost the same signatures?

Tags: c#

I have following methods:

```
public UISchemaBuilder AddText(UISchemaTextParameters parameters) =>
   Add(parameters);

public UISchemaBuilder AddTextLine(UISchemaTextLineParameters parameters) =>
   Add(parameters);

public  UISchemaBuilder AddTextArea(UISchemaTextAreaParameters parameters) =>
   Add(parameters);

 // etc
```

All methods return `UISchemaBuilder` and argument type is custom class which represent parameters. I will show an example:

```
public class UISchemaTextAreaParameters
    : UISchemaParameters
{
     public UISchemaTextAreaParameters() {}
     
     public  UISchemaTextAreaParameters(NameLocalizedTitle nameTitle)
         : base(nameTitle)
     {
     }

     public uint? MaxLength {get;set;}|

     public override UIControlAttribute UIControlGet() =>
        new UIControlStringAttribute()
     {
        Parameters = new UISchemaStringFieldParameters
        {
            MaxLength = MaxLength
        },
        IsMultiple = true
     } 
}
```

And all this arguments inherit `UISchemaParameters`:

```
public abstract class UISchemaParameters
{
    protected UISchemaParameters() { }

    protected UISchemaParameters(NameLocalizedTitle nameTitle)
    {
        Name = nameTitle.Name;
        Title = nameTitle.Title;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public bool? IsReadOnly { get; set; }

    public bool? IsRequired { get; set; }

    public bool? IsMultiple { get; set; }

    public abstract UIControlAttribute UIControlGet();
}
```

SO what's the problem: all methods call the same method, all methods have almost the same signature. How to refactor my code?

`Add` method:

```
private UISchemaBuilder Add(UISchemaParemeters parameters)
{
   CreateUISchemaItem(
     parameters.Name,
     parameters.Title,
     parameters.IsRequired,
     parameters.IsReadOnly,
     parameters.IsMultiple,
     parameters.UIControlGet());

   return this;
}
```

Comment: What is `Add` that you are calling in all of the implementations?

Comment: The signature isn't the same at all - each method has a completely different name. Is that intentional? If `Add` accepts `UISchemaParameters` you don't need the extra methods unless it' for convenience. You could create a generic method restricted to `UISchemaParameters` parameters with `Add<T>(T parameters) where T:UISchemaParameters` but that's no better than just `Add(UISchemaParameters)` in this case

Comment: I added `Add` method so you can see it rn

Comment: While there may be a way to unify all of them, do you actually _want_ this? `TextArea` is different from `TextLine` probably for a reason and you do not want to reintroduce the issues that come from combining both.

Comment: It depends whether you can do the same thing for all the parameter types or whether the methods must be specific. In the former case you must use a switch if you reduce to one method, which is not any better than it is now.

Comment: _do you actually want this_.. Actually I don't know, it's comfortable for users to use but it's not comfortable for me to read so I wanna find smth like best practice

Answer (score 1):

You could introduce strategy pattern into play.
You have interface:

```
interface ITextStrategy<TParameters>
    where TParameters : UISchemaParameters
{
    UISchemaBuilder AddText(TParameters parameters);
}
```

You create implementations of this interface for each of `XXXParameters` type.

You register those implementations in your DI.

To make it prettier you add factory:

```
interface ITextStrategyFactory
{
    ITextStrategy<TParameters> Create<TParameters>()
        where TParameters : UISchemaParameters;
}
```

Which implementation just resolves strategy from DI, but you now separate your code from DI implementation. You also register this one in DI.

In your client code you inject factory, and when you need to "add text" you call:

```
var strategy = this.textStrategyFactory.Create<UISchemaTextLineParameters>();
var builder = strategy.AddText(parameters);
```